Does white balance in context of direct reflections and glare needs to be treated in another way than it is in diffuse reflections?

Given that I have a few images of a red apple, taken on a yellowish sunset.

Given that the goal is to see real apple color without the yellowish light from the evening sun

Given that in order to solve the issue I use a well-known technique of white balance adjusting called "white patch" where I choose some area of the image known to be white in real life, see how far it is from being white, and adjust all three RGB channels in an adjacent way.


Problem:
If I take an image from an angle where no "clear reflections" and no glare from the yellowish evening sun, the white balance technique works just great, and my apple from yellowish comes back to be red, as it is in its Ground Truth.
But, if I take an image from an angle where I see kind of a mirror-like reflection or glare, the white balance technique does not work in such an area of an apple, and this specific part of an apple remains yellowish.
Question:
I more or less understand why it happens but I miss some physical terminology to formulate the problem. Guess it has to do with the difference between the reflection types. Can someone please help me formulate what is happening, and then, maybe five me some advice on how to solve this issue?

Glare is always going to appear white in a camera, the pixels get saturated, and the camera clips them to equal values of RGB(=white).  If you color correct white you will not get white back.

It appears yellow because it actually is.
First off, obligatory post of The Dress and the XKCD rendering of it which was carefully designed to let most people see both observed color schemes.  This is what you are fighting.
Your object is lit.  I haven't seen the picture you are referring to, but I can venture a guess that it is outside simply due to the problem you are experiencing.  Thus your object is lit by the sun and the sky.  Diffuse surfaces are reflecting the light which your brain is interpreting as white.
For sake of argument, let's say your picture includes a white-card, which you can a-priori assume needs to be interpreted as white by the viewers of your picture. Your card is lit the same way the apple is: by the sun and the sky.  So a correction to white balance which makes the card white will make your apple appear correct.
However, in the case of specular reflections (aka "glare"), most of the light is coming from the sun rather than the sky.  The sky is making specular reflections too, but they're less noticeable.  The regions you are focusing on are the ones where the balance of photons recived from the apple is shifted more towards the sun.
Because the blue light of the sun gets scattered as it approaches us, then sun's light appears yellow.  That scattered blue light is what makes the sky blue.  So since those points in the picture are lit more by the sun, they must appear more yellow, because they actually are more yellow.
I believe that is the end of the physics part of the problem.  Your regions with glare appear yellow because they are yellow, and there is no physical correction that can be done to make them not-yellow.
If you were to ask a related question on Photography.SE, you might ask how you can process the image to reduce the yellowness of the glare without disrupting the rest of the picture.  Such a post processing step would not by physics related, but would instead be a perception based approach designed to convince the human brain of your viewers to accept the colors as you, the artist, wished to convey.

Sir thank you! Do I get right the following:
1)Measuring how far the white in the whitecard has moved from being "actually white", and then applying those offsets to correct back all the pixels in the image, DID work even in glare areas, but not "enough" unlike in the areas of diffuse reflections.
Right?
2) The "whitecard" was "toilet paper" = diffuse reflections. Using a polished whitecard will make correction offsets more precise leading to a better correction in glare areas of an apple, but to an overcorrection in areas with diffuse reflections of an apple.
Right?

Correct.  Although to use a "polished whitecard," you would probably need to have a curved surface to guarantee that you get at least one point on the card that glints.
